# C - is there a way to work with strings which have NULL character in the middle

Tags: c, arrays, string, null, char

Is it possible to have strings with `NULL` character somewhere except the end and work with them? Like get their size, use `strcat`, etc?

I have some ideas:

1) Write your own function for getting length (or something else), which is going to iterate over a string. If it meets a `NULL` char, it is going to check the next char of the string. If it is not `NULL` - continue counting chars. But it may (and WILL!) eventually lead to situation when you are reading memory OUTSIDE of the char array. So it is a bad idea.

2) Use `sizeof(array)/sizeof(type)`, eg `sizeof(input)/sizeof(char)`. That is going to work pretty good I think.

Do you have any other ideas on how this can be done? Maybe there are some function which I am not aware of (C newbie alert :))?

Comment: it's possible, but then you can't use the standard string functions on them. you can't have your cake and eat it as well.

Comment: I think your first idea will work if you add 2 `null` characters at the end. Then two consecutive `null` bytes mean the end of the total string, I might be wrong, there might be a situation where this could fail. I was going to point out what Marc B just commented. What I can't think of is a use case? Why don't you just store the total length of it somewhere?

Comment: @iharob, I was just wondering if that is possible somehow :). Writing a library which can convert text to base16 && back, so I was thinking about how should I solve this problem. Figured out I'd just let the user pass required size as an argument. But still pretty interested in others' ideas

Comment: In c a string is simpply an array of char. sizeof(yourstring) gives ou the length you need. What you cannot use is string.h functions, like strlen. Each one of that function works only with null terminated string, then stops at the first 0x00 that is found.

Comment: You can mimic the Pascal strings, that have the length prepended to them in the beginning. But once again, you will have to rewrite the whole strings library.

Comment: No.  `sizeof(yourstring)` gives you the length of the char array, but that doesn't tell you how much of the array contains actual data.  And it doesn't even do that on a `char *`.

Comment: I just thought of a situation where will not work, if your input string contains several consecutive `0` bytes, so it is not possible that way.

Comment: sizeof is a compile tine operator, so will not be usable for data acquired at run time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only really safe method I can think of is to use "Pascal"-type strings (that is, something that has a string header and assorted other data associated with it).

Something like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int len, allocated;
    char *data;
  } my_string;
```

You would then have to implement pretty much every string manipulation function yourself. Keeping both the "length of the string" and "the size of the allocation" allows you to have an allocation that's larger than the current contents, this may make repeated string concatenation cheaper (allows an amortized O(1) append).

Comment: Umm, what is "the length of the allocation"? You mean the amount of bytes allocated for the `data`?

Comment: @victor Yes, the size of the allocation. It's possibly distict from the length (and keeping the two distinct allows for a fair bit of optimization down the line).

Answer (score 4):

You can have an array of `char`, either statically or dynamically allocated, that contains a zero byte in the middle, but only the part up to and including the zero can be considered a "string" in the standard C sense.  Only that part will be recognized or considered by the standard library's string functions.

You can use a different terminator -- say two zeroes in a row -- and write your own string functions, but that just pushes off the problem.  What happens when you need two zeroes in the middle of your string?  In any case, you need to exercise even more care in this case than in the ordinary string case to ensure that your custom strings are properly terminated.  You also have to be certain to avoid using them with the standard string functions.

If your special strings are stored in `char` array of known size then you can get the length of the overall array via `sizeof`, but that doesn't tell you what portion of the array contains meaningful data.  It also doesn't help with any of the other string functions you might want to perform, and it does nothing for you if your handle on the pseudo-strings is a `char *`.

If you are contemplating custom string functions anyway, then you should consider string objects that have an explicit length stored with them.  For example:

```
struct my_string {
    unsigned allocated, length;
    char *contents;
};
```

Your custom functions then handle objects of that type, being certain to do the right thing with the `length` member.  There is no explicit terminator, so these strings can contain any `char` value.  Also, you can be certain not to mixed these up with standard strings.

Comment: Per @Vatine, added an `allocated` member.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you store the length of the array of chars then you can have strings with nul characters or even without a terminating nul.

```
 struct MyString
 {
     int length;
     char*  buffer;
  };
```

And then you would have to write all your equivalent functions for managing the string.

The bstring library http://bstring.sourceforge.net and Microsofts BSTR (uses wide chars) are existing libraries that work in this way and also offer some compatibilty with c-style strings.

pros - getting the length of the string is quick
cons - the strings need to be dynamically allocated.